# Create a TabControl programmatically in WPF(C#)

Tags: c#, wpf-4.0

I am a newbie to C# and WPF in particular and  I'm wondering how to create a TabControl programatically(not via xaml). I have the following code:

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
   TabControl c = new TabControl() 
  }
```

But the TabControl is not created when the button is clicked. Could someone please give me a basic example on how to create  a TabControl programatically. This may also help me understand how WPF works(I am more used to Swing Java). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `TabControl` to some part of your window.

Specifically, you should add it to the `Children` collection of some kind of panel.

Comment: @EShindler: `somePanel.Children.Add(c)`

Comment: @EShindler: You also need to add the canvas to the window.  (just like in Java)

Comment: Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            this.AddChild(canvas);
            canvas.Children.Add(c); This doesn't work either

Comment: `this` isn't a panel and cannot have multiple children.

Comment: The class 'extends' Window: public partial class MainWindow : Window. I'm trying to add the canvas to the window-unsuccessfully.

Comment: @EShindler: You can only add control to a panel; other containers (eg, `Window`) can only have a single child.

Comment: Done: The following seems to work:Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            this.Content = canvas;
            canvas.Children.Add(c); Thanks very much for your help

Comment: What does this mean:could not copy obj\debug\wpfapplication1.exe to bin\debug\wpfapplication1.exe

Comment: This happens when I add the code: Window3 window = new Window3();
            window.Show();

Comment: @EShindler: VS can't compile your application while an old copy is running.